# Не могу исправить ошибку конкатенации Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

```
file = open("bin2.txt", 'w')
with open('bin2.txt', 'r'):
    for i in range(1000,9999):
        a = bin(i)[2:]
        file.write(str(a +'\n'))
file.close()

file0 = open("bin3.txt", 'w')
with open ("bin3.txt", 'r'):
    for i in range(1000,9999):
        newNum = ''
        while i > 0:
            newNum = str(i % 3) + newNum
            i //= 3
            file0.write(str(i+ '\n')) # **Здесь**
file0.close()
```

Comment: ошибка в конкатенации, нельзя строку приклеить к числу

Comment: а должно быть сохранение в троичной системе с переносом строки

Comment: нельзя просто так перевести число в строку, как видите там цикл который переводит все числа в указанном промежутке в троичную систему, если я возьму и просто переведу, будет верно кодировано только одно число а все что стоит далее просто склеится как текст

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все правильно, вы в строке `file0.write(str(i+ '\n'))` пытаетесь сконкатенировать integer и string переменные, попробуйте сначала привести integer к string, а потом проводить конкатенацию `file0.write(str(i) + '\n')`